# getting ffmpeg.dll failed to load message in my c# video application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed a Winform application which has a Panel as Main Screen and two other panels on each side for previous and next video. and Two buttons which helps the Application to traverse through different videos and set it to the main panel. I have 21 videos now...... 
This is My code....

```
public void loadvideo2(int a)
    {

            int width = viewscreen.Width;
            int height = viewscreen.Height;
            int width1 = nxtpnl.Width;
            int height1 = nxtpnl.Height;
            int width2 = prepnl.Width;
            int height2 = prepnl.Height;

            video = new Video(vpath[a]);
            video.Owner = viewscreen;
            video.Stop();
            viewscreen.Size = new Size(width, height);

            video1 = new Video(vpath[a + 1]);
            video1.Owner = nxtpnl;
            video1.Stop();
            nxtpnl.Size = new Size(width1, height1);

            video2 = new Video(vpath[a - 1]);
            video2.Owner = prepnl;
            video2.Stop();
            prepnl.Size = new Size(width2, height2);

            plystpBtn.BackgroundImage = Video_Project.Properties.Resources.Style_Play_icon__1_;
            plystpBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

            trckstatus.Minimum = Convert.ToInt32(video.CurrentPosition);
            trckstatus.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(video.Duration);

            duration = CalculateTime(video.Duration);
            playposition = "0:00:00";
            posdurtrclbl.Text = playposition + "/" + duration;

            b = a;
            vlbl.Text = "Video" + Convert.ToString(b);
        } 

 private void preBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videono += 1;
        if (videono <= vcount-1)
        {
            loadvideo2(videono);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("File Not Found!!!");
    }

 private void nxtBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            videono -= 1;
            if (videono >= 0)
            {
                loadvideo2(videono);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("FIle Not Found!!!");
    }
```

now while i am traversing through the videos by pressing buttons its working fine till the 16th video where i am getting an error message

```
ffmpeg.dll failed to load
```

can any one help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. It was probably a memory consumption issue.

```
public void loadvideo2(int a)
    {


            int width = viewscreen.Width;
            int height = viewscreen.Height;
            int width1 = nxtpnl.Width;
            int height1 = nxtpnl.Height;
            int width2 = prepnl.Width;
            int height2 = prepnl.Height;

            video.Dispose();


            video = new Video(vpath[a]);
            video.Owner = viewscreen;
            video.Stop();
            viewscreen.Size = new Size(width, height);

            video1 = new Video(vpath[a + 1]);
            video1.Owner = nxtpnl;
            video1.Stop();
            nxtpnl.Size = new Size(width1, height1);

            video2 = new Video(vpath[a - 1]);
            video2.Owner = prepnl;
            video2.Stop();
            prepnl.Size = new Size(width2, height2);



            plystpBtn.BackgroundImage = Video_Project.Properties.Resources.Style_Play_icon__1_;
            plystpBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

            trckstatus.Minimum = Convert.ToInt32(video.CurrentPosition);
            trckstatus.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(video.Duration);

            duration = CalculateTime(video.Duration);
            playposition = "0:00:00";
            posdurtrclbl.Text = playposition + "/" + duration;

            b = a;
            vlbl.Text = "Video" + Convert.ToString(b);
            video1.Dispose();
            video2.Dispose();
        }
```